How does the operator "Pointwise Logical Not"(.!) work in Swift?
I learn Swift and use Swift operators (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/operator-declarations) and saw the operator "Pointwise Logical Not"(.!). I started Googling and came across a question on stackoverflow(What is functionality of Pointwise Equal, Pointwise less than, and Pointwise greater in Swift? ), they told me about the SIMD protocol and gave a link to the documentation, but I did not find an operator among the operators of this protocol .! . Could you help me with an example with this operator. Thank you in advance

main.swift:131:9: error: type 'Bool' does not conform to protocol 'SIMDScalar'
let z = SIMD3(true, false, true)


main.swift:132:10: error: generic parameter 'Storage' could not be inferred
var yy = .!z


main.swift:131:9: error: type 'Bool' does not conform to protocol 'SIMDScalar'
let z = SIMD3(true, false, true)


main.swift:132:10: error: generic parameter 'Storage' could not be inferred
var yy = .!z


It works, but as the error states, Bool does not conform to the protocol. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/simdscalar under 'Relationships' for valid types.

I think your issue comes from trying to make SIMD values filled with booleans. SIMD types only ever store ints/floats/doubles. To store booleans, there's a dedicated type called SIMDMask, which for example, is the result of operators like .==, .<, etc.
.! negates every boolean member of a SIMD mask, e.g.
import simd

let a: SIMD2<Int> = [10, 20]
let b: SIMD2<Int> = [ 0, 30]
let exampleMask: SIMDMask<SIMD2<Int>> = a .< b
let invertedMask = .!exampleMask

print( exampleMask) // => [false,  true]
print(invertedMask) // => [ true, false]

The result of a .< b is the same as .!(a .>= b), in the same way that for single scalar values, !(a < b) is the same as !(a >= b).

Thank you very much, you helped me in this difficult matter.
